# Use tar to compress file tar.gz with password

Tags: passwords, command, gnu, tar

I use `tar -czf test.tar.gz test/` to compress `test` forlder to `test.tar.gz` . Now, I want compress to `test.tar.gz` with password `"mypass"` How can I do?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/162624/how-to-password-protect-gzip-files-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 31):

Neither the `tar format` nor the `gz format` has built-in support for password-protecting files.
Use crypt or gpg on the 
Refer this [encrypt-and-decrypt-files-with-a-password](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-with-a-password.html) for more info.

```
tar cvvjf - /path/to/files | ccrypt > backup.tar.bz2.cpt
```

or

```
ccrypt backup.tar.bz2
```

And then to decrypt:

```
cat ../backup.tar.bz2 | ccrypt -d | tar -xjf -
```

You can also use zip

```
zip -e file.zip file
```

Will ask you on a prompt for a password. It is more secure then passing the password via the command line via `zip -P password`.

Comment: But I want enter password on my compress command. Can you help me with this?

Comment: zip -e instead of zip -P so that it prompts the password instead.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/162624/how-to-password-protect-gzip-files-on-the-command-line