# Give command prompt inputs through nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to unzip a password protected zip file in windows using nodejs and I'm using tar command to do this via node child process.
The problem is, there is a prompt to enter the password but I can't find a way to pass the password that stored in the pwd variable.

```
const pwd = 'password';
exec(`tar -xf ${filePath}}`,callback);

  function callback(err,stdout,stdin){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
```

Comment: tar does not support passwords. Use other utils -like zip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use tar to compress file tar.gz with password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734101/use-tar-to-compress-file-tar-gz-with-password)

Comment: I'm creating an electron app for windows so I don't think zip command is available on windows by default